# how to transfer a home-dir structure from one linux PC to another linux PC

Tags: linux, tar

How can I transfer via tar the whole /home/.. tree with all the file attributes from one linux to another linux PC? I know I could write it to a tar file but I have not so much space on the target. Is there a way to pipe it with the tar command?

Comment: Yes, you can pipe it via ssh, but I would use rsync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use rsync and ssh

### Set up ssh

You need to install `openssh-client` on the receiving computer and `openssh-server` on the sending computer. Use the help distribution specific help docs for help setting this up.

### `rsync` files

Go onto the 2nd computer and rsync the folder from the other first pc.

```
rsync -av ipofpc1:/home/ /home/
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways, but in this case I'd recommend using [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

- First you need to install a SSH server on the target computer if you don't alrady have one running. For example on Debian/Ubuntu/Mint you'd do `apt-get install openssh-server`.
- Then install rsync on the computer with the source folder. For example : `apt-get install rsync`.

And finally you can use rsync like this:

```
rsync --razh user@YOUR_OTHER_COMPUTER:/destination/path /home/
```